# ios design in iphone SE but I want to make the design in iphone 8 plus

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, responsive-design, sketch-3

I have got the application design in iphone SE (sketch). But I am designing app in iphone 8 plus. I want the exact sizes and dims for iphone 8 plus. But when I change the simulator I sketch it only changes the screen sizes not all the elements.

Comment: I suggest you read about auto layout.  You should use constraints so that your app adjusts to the device screen size.

Comment: Hello Akhlaq Ahmad, please check my all auto layout video it's all about constrain means Autolayout it's solved your responsive design issue ! Thank You                      https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZGlgSg6Rwvo_dd8Lf8v02xxoEI3bDuGd

Answer (score 1):

Open your storyboard and try clicking as picture below :

[image]

Change the view to iPhone 8 Plus :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As i know, Sketch allow you to use constraits for controls. Please, see [here](https://sketchapp.com/docs/layer-basics/constraints/) for more information.
If we talk about development process - auto-layout can help you with problem.
More about auto-layout you can find [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH7-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

In the bottom of the Storyboard you can find this button 
[image]

Click on it and you can choose what device you set your layout for.

Answer (score 0):

All you gotta do is this: Add missing constraints

[image: Add missing constraint]